# Slickgrid - dataview not updated

Tags: javascript, filter, slickgrid

I am applying a filter on slick grid data, it changes the number of records in footer but does not refresh the data in table and always show all records.

Code :

```
$('#shade-number').keyup(function(e) {
       // clear on Esc
       if (e.which == 27) {
          this.value = "";
       }

        searchList = $.trim(this.value.toLowerCase()).split(' ');
        dataViewAdd.setFilter(gridFilter);  
        gridPo.invalidate();
        this.focus();
});

function gridFilter(rec) {
    var found;

    for (i = 0; i < searchList.length; i += 1) {
        found = false;
        $.each(rec, function(obj, objValue) {
            if (typeof objValue !== 'undefined' && objValue != null 
            && objValue.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchList[i]) != -1) {
                found = true;
                return false; //this breaks the $.each loop
            }
        });
        if (!found) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

[image]

In table footer it says `Showing all 4 rows` but in table all records are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have the OnRowCountChanged and OnRowsChanged events hooked up.
You should always start with a working example, such as:

http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html

and modify it to your needs. Then if something goes wrong, you can retrace your changes step by step until it works.
Also, being able to post a link to a fully working example is a lot easier to debug. I'd bet the problem is in code not mentioned above.